# Duplicate content on homepage of custom made PHP script

Tags: php, html, css

I coded a simple php blog. On the homepage it displays the most viewed post and also links to the actual page of the post similar to the frontpage of a wordpress blog for example.

How to avoid duplicate content for SEO purposes? Is there a certain html tag or code for search engines to prevent considering the post on homepage and the actual page duplicate??

Thanks

Comment: how it would differ?? it's a php script so obviously be index.php :)

Answer (score 0):

Homepage is the page that index.php or index.html outputs, even if this is a redirection to an inner file. If you want to make a cms for example with an admin panel and offer different templates, styles and plugins, and decide to divert the design code from the engine code, it is is functionally common sense that you 'll include the template in other template-folders (to keep the filesystem clean, well-organised, and easily accessible from the design work). In this way, admin panel will insert and update your site parameters to the database and the root index file will read those parameters from the db. So the best you have to do for SEO means is to create and keep well-informed all the xml files (sitemap, feed, rss, atom), include keywords (taxonomy),tags and metadata, coherence at internal and external links, keep a clean design output and a lot more parameters that needs a lot of space and time to analyze.

Comment: sorry can't get you :( what i can tell is that the homepage displays the most viewed post on the homepage and it's displayed fully not a summary so it would be definitely considered duplicate

Comment: i don't think that i will make sitemap and feed or at least till now but i find other simple custom made sites similar to mine but don't know how they manage avoiding the homepage duplicate pos

Comment: who speaks about duplicate? If you type http://domain.com what is the output? it could be http://domain.com?id=home or http://domain.com/home.php or anything. This is what the search engine consider as homepage (from what I know, please if you know sth more tell me).

Comment: please, read google about sitemaps http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184 it is really very easy to produce dynamically

Comment: ok here is a simple example of what i mean: this is a link to homepage of a site: http://www.wonderlol.com/ now go to this url: http://www.wonderlol.com/taylor-swift-failed-like-a-boss_7625.html and you will find they are exact content

Comment: why? what the need to be the same?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27903/discussion-between-nikos-and-michael-samuel)